# How to obtain certain value from URL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Given this URL:

```
www.google.com/hsisn/-#++#/valuetoretrive/+#(#(/.html
```

The value to is between 4th and 5th slash.
How to retrieve that particular value using SQL Server 2008?

Comment: Which dbms? (You'll probably need product specific functionality here...)

Comment: What url has to do with SQL? Do you store url's in database?

Comment: Yes URL stored in database

Comment: URL size may vary. The logic is the value between 4 TH and 5 TH slash

Comment: Have you tried to use Linq instead of SQL? Have you tried to use CTE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function in SQL server to get the `nth` occurrence of a value, the only function is [`CHARINDEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx), which will retrieve the first instance after the specified starting position. So the only way to utilise this is to cascade each value found, i.e:

- Find the position of 1st `"/"`
- Find the position of the next `"/"` after the first one
- Find the position of the next `"/"` after the second one

So each calculation requires the result of the previous one, which to get the 5th occurrence gets fairly messy, but not impossible if you use `CROSS APPLY` to reuse your results. Once you have the position of the 4th and 5th occurrence you can use [`SUBSTRING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) to extract the text:

```
SELECT  t.url,
        Value = SUBSTRING(t.url, p4.Position, p5.Position - p4.Position - 1)
FROM    (SELECT url = 'URL:/www.google.com/hsisn/-#++#/valuetoretrive/+#(#(/.html') AS t
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT 1 + CHARINDEX('/', url)) AS p1 (Position)
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT 1 + CHARINDEX('/', url, p1.Position)) AS p2 (Position)
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT 1 + CHARINDEX('/', url, p2.Position)) AS p3 (Position)
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT 1 + CHARINDEX('/', url, p3.Position)) AS p4 (Position)
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT 1 + CHARINDEX('/', url, p4.Position)) AS p5 (Position);
```

---

**ADDENDUM**

The other option you have, if you want more flexibility, i.e. get the text between the 50th and 51st occurrence, is to utilise a split function. [The most efficient way to split strings is with a CLR function](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings), but the next best T-SQL only method for this purpose is to use a numbers table to split your string, and in the absence of this create your own using stacked CTEs.

I will assume that you don't have a numbers table and use a stacked CTE in the interest of a complete working example.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split (@StringToSplit VARCHAR(1000), @Delimiter CHAR(1))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(   WITH N1 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) AS t (n)), 
    N2 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N1 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N1 AS N2),
    Numbers (N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY n1.N) FROM N1 CROSS JOIN N2 AS N2)
    SELECT  Position = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY n.N),
            Value = SUBSTRING(@StringToSplit, n.N, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @StringToSplit, n.N + 1), 0), LEN(@StringToSplit)) - n.N)

    FROM    Numbers AS n
    WHERE   SUBSTRING(@Delimiter + @StringToSplit, n.N, 1) = @Delimiter
);
```

Which you can call fairly simply:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (URL VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL);
INSERT @Table VALUES ('URL:/www.google.com/hsisn/-#++#/valuetoretrive/+#(#(/.html');
SELECT  s.*
FROM    @Table AS t
        CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(t.URL, '/') AS s;
```

Which gives you:

```
Position    Value
---------------------
1           URL:
2           www.google.com
3           hsisn
4           -#++#
5           valuetoretrive
6           +#(#(
7           .htm
```

So you can simply select the 5th value from this by adding a where clause.:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (URL VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL);
INSERT @Table 
VALUES 
    ('URL:/www.google.com/hsisn/-#++#/valuetoretrive/+#(#(/.html'),
    ('URL:/www.google.com/hsisn/-#++#/valuetoretrive2/+#(#(/.html');
SELECT  t.URL, s.Value
FROM    @Table AS t
        CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(t.URL, '/') AS s
WHERE   s.Position = 5;
```

Comment: Thanks Gareth for your kindly help

Comment: Good job and nice explained!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know before hand the lenght of the url or the value to retrieve or slash positions you can use this snipet

```
declare @uri varchar(max) = 'URL:/www.google.com/hsisn/-#++#/valuetoretrive/+#(#(/.html'

,@startAt int = 0
,@slashCount int = 0

while @slashCount < 5
begin

   set @startAt = CHARINDEX('/',@uri);
   set @slashCount = @slashCount + 1;

   if (@slashCount = 5)
      set @uri = SUBSTRING(@uri, 0, @startAt)
   else
      set @uri = SUBSTRING(@uri, @startAt + 1, LEN(@uri))


   -- debug info
   select @startAt, @slashCount, @uri
end
```

it ill decompose the string, getting slash positions until it find #4 and #5 slash and get anything between.

**OUTPUT**

```
5           1           www.google.com/hsisn/-#++#/valuetoretrive/+#(#(/.html
15          2           hsisn/-#++#/valuetoretrive/+#(#(/.html
6           3           -#++#/valuetoretrive/+#(#(/.html
6           4           valuetoretrive/+#(#(/.html
15          5           valuetoretrive
```

You also can get it using a cross apply instead of a while loop but this way you code ill not need to get big and messy to get anything after the n > 10, n-th slah.